# Parse.com include related field array on save

Tags: javascript, rest, parse-platform

Is it possible to include related field on save i.e.

```
save(null, {
    success: function(updatedObject) {
            // Is there a way to include another field which is an array of pointers either here or before save()?
    },
    error: function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Only when you query for an item can you get included objects, by using the `include` method.

```
var query = new Parse.Query('myClass');
query.include('arrayOfPointersColumn');
query.first().then(function(result) {
  // you can access the full parse objects inside the result object.
  var otherObjects = result.get('arrayOfPointersColumn');
  console.log(otherObjects);
});
```

Comment: Ok, thats what I gathered from the doc, but I was hoping for a more efficient way to do this. So, if I need to get it done, then I need to save, then on success, do query and send the resulting object, right? Also the object in question in _User, which I am getting from request.user. Thoughts?

Comment: If you're getting the user from request.user, yeah, you won't get the included items... but, you can Fetch them... Going off the example I posted, except assuming the pointer column is unfetched..  Parse.Object.fetchAll(otherObjects).then(function(fetchedObjects) { ...